# JHipster-registry blank page

Tags: spring, webpack, jhipster, yarnpkg, jhipster-registry

I'm trying to compile a frontend and typed `yarn start` to start the frontend of jhipster-registry. However I get this error which I can't fix. Moreover, the page is either blank or I got 404. I have enclosed the whole stack trace:

```
    warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
    $ node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base
    × ｢wds｣: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
     - configuration.module.rules[6].exclude should be one of these:
       RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? } | [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
       -> One or multiple rule conditions
       Details:
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude should be an instance of RegExp
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude should be a string.
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude should be an instance of function
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude[0] should be an instance of RegExp
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude[0]: The provided value "./src/main/webapp/index.html" is not an absolute path!
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude[0] should be an instance of function
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude[0] should be an array:
          [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude[0] should be an object.
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude should be an object.
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude[0] should be an instance of RegExp
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude[0]: The provided value "./src/main/webapp/index.html" is not an absolute path!
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude[0] should be an instance of function
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude[0] should be an array:
          [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
        * configuration.module.rules[1].exclude[0] should be an object.
        * configuration.module.rules[5].exclude should be an instance of RegExp
        * configuration.module.rules[5].exclude should be a string.
        * configuration.module.rules[5].exclude should be an instance of function
        * configuration.module.rules[5].exclude[0] should be an instance of RegExp
        * configuration.module.rules[5].exclude[0]: The provided value "node_modules" is not an absolute path!
        * configuration.module.rules[5].exclude[0] should be an instance of function
        * configuration.module.rules[5].exclude[0] should be an array:
* inner part which I cut
        * configuration.module.rules[6].exclude[0] should be an object.
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: you  must run yarn insatll

Comment: i’ve done that.

Comment: I ran yarn upgrade then yarn install and still got the same error. :(

Comment: Which version of nodejs?

Comment: 10.13.0 running on Windows

Comment: I cameacross this thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/42060243/… which seems to be somehow related but I don't know where is my webpack.config.js in jhipster.